What vCard like standard is this?
I'm trying to parse vCards received through PBAP from my phone, but the open source libraries I used keep on bugging out on me.
When comparing RFC6350, specifically the telephone object, it does not match the given example listed in the RFC.
RFC states:
TEL;VALUE=uri;TYPE=home:tel:+33-01-23-45-67

PBAP receives:
TEL;HOME:+33-01-23-45-67

This is different and bugs out the parser. However, the PBAP received vCard does begin and end with BEGIN:VCARD and END:VCARD and contains the VERSION:2.1 field
Who can guide me in the right direction and suggest some C/C++ libraries?
